# How to get the number of distinct words by length in Spark (python)?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have the following code that results in a list with tuples.

```
 words \
  .map(lambda word: (word.lower(), 1))\
  .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)\
  .filter(lambda(x,y): y >= 3)
```

The tuple list looks as followed:

```
[(u'pardon', 6),
 (u'four', 8),
 (u'sleep', 6),
 (u'lory', 7),
 (u'pardon', 6)]
```

**How can I extend the code, so I can get the number of words by length?** It should look like this:

```
[(6,2),
 (7,1),
 (8,1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `_.tolower()` with `len(_)`:

```
word.map(lambda word: (len(word), 1))
```

Comment: That shows the length of the word, but it des not show the number of words by length as in the example.